# mysql trigger delete on insert syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger to remove a certain number of rows when the table hits a limit. This is what I have currently:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(rowa) FROM tableA ) > 10

THEN

DELETE FROM table WHERE dateinsert IN (
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT dateinsert FROM tableA ORDER BY dateinsert ASC limit 1
) AS P
)
end if;
```

pypmyadmin prompt that i have a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your sql **DELETE** statement. You cannot use the keyword **table**.
Below is an example.

I have changed **table** to **tableA** in the delete statement.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(rowa) FROM tableA ) > 10 THEN
  DELETE FROM tableA WHERE dateinsert IN 
   (SELECT dateinsert FROM
    (SELECT dateinsert FROM tableA ORDER BY dateinsert ASC limit 1) AS tmp1);
END IF;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks. But I encountered the following error: This verison of MariaDB doesnt yet sypport LIMIT, IN/ALL,ANY/SOME subquery

Comment: Hi Ken, sorry about that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Tom, still having error at "syntax near end if". Separately, the query and subquery is working well when executed. Let me try to work on it. Thanks again.

Comment: There was a missing semicolon at the end of the DELETE statement, just before END IF.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks again. able to insert the trigger. On a side note, it encounter "Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger" when the row hit 10. I assumed that the table cant be updated as it is locked by the trigger. do you have any work around for this?